# EMR Notebooks running Spark - how to install additional libraries from a private github branch

Tags: apache-spark, jupyter-notebook, amazon-emr

I would like to install a python library into the EMR Notebook virtualenv as in `sc.install_pypi_package("arrow==0.14.0", "https://pypi.org/simple")`.

The python library is not released as a pypi package, but rather sits on a custom branch on a private github repository. How can I refer to the git repo and provide the relevant git credentials for AWS EMR for this to work?

Would this library be available also to the Spark EMR cluster (UDF functions) too, or would it be available just for the jupyter notebook ?

Answer (score 2):

You can install it when initializing the EMR Cluster using [Bootstrap Actions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-plan-bootstrap.html). This way the library will be available within Spark Cluster and the Jupiter Notebook.

In bootsrap script, you could use `pip` to get the lib from GitHub:

```
pip install -e git+https://github.com/some_repo.git
```

See [pip_install git](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install/#git) for how to clone from GitHub using pip.

Comment: Great. And what about the EMR notebook virtualenv (isolated per notebook)? Does sc.install_pypi_package() supports that syntax?

Comment: @blackbishop Hi I also got into same issue want to install pyspark iforest library, i dont know how to do that. How can i do that using bootstrap script? i could not find where i can add such pip install command in bootstrap. could you please guide me.